# Again: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

so again this error:
"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type ClientiController : Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor"

This error comes only when I publish the site, NOT in localhost when i debug it.

These are lines code:

settings

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultWmsApi",
           routeTemplate: "apiwms/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

controller

```
public class ClientiController : ApiController
{
    public ClientiController() {}

    [HttpGet]
    public List<ClienteItem> GetAllCustomers()
    {
            List<ClienteItem> elencoClienti = new List<ClienteItem>();
            foreach (var cliente in Cliente.GetAllCustomers())
            {
                elencoClienti.Add(new ClienteItem()
                {
                    ID = cliente.ID,
                    RagioneSociale = cliente.RagioneSociale
                });
            }
            return elencoClienti;        
    }
}
```

'ClienteItem' and 'Cliente' classes have parameterless public constructor.

- JS

  ```
     var self = this;
      axios.get("<%=Utils.AbsoluteWebRoot %>apiwms/Clienti").then(function (response) {
          self.clienti = response.data;
      });
  ```

Any help?
Thanks.
Ingd

Comment: this controller 'xxx' has parameter less constructor??

Comment: I edit question text: the controller is ClientiController .